# Generic Entity Framework function with Func<T, bool> predicate throws memory overflow exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, memory-leaks

I am facing a weird problem in my project with Entity Framework. I have this below generic function to get data by specific where predicate:

```
    public List<T> GetByProperty<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext(_connectionString))
        {
            IDbSet<T> dbSet = context.Set<T>();
            var entityList = dbSet.Where(predicate).ToList();
            return entityList;
        }
    }
```

It was working perfectly until now. We have made some changes in the database. Made some identity column from integer to long. As a result when I am calling this method with a predicate which associates these long ID column, then I am getting "MemoryOverflow Exception". For an example, I am calling with the following predicate/where clause:

`GetByProperty<Member>(m => m.Id == aMember.Id)`

It was working perfectly when the Id column was integer. But now it is long (bigint in database) and it gives memory overflow exception. I searched a lot but seems like it is a new kind of problem which baffles me.

Comment: `Func<T, bool>` is causing loading the whole table in memory and filtering there. Use `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` instead to let filtering happen in database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like charm!